# What do I do with the mechanical pig?

Tags: jazzpunk

I've hunted down and defeated the mechanical pig, but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do next. How do I proceed? (The QR code on the side tells me what I *need* to do, but I don't know *how* to do it.)

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 5):

The answer can be found here: http://steamcommunity.com/app/250260/discussions/0/540732889243732067/

Go to the front of the hotel, you can place the pig on a spit.

Answer (score 3):

You need to go to the sign that says "Kai Tak Hotel." Near the clam there is a fire where you need to cook the pig.

Answer (score 1):

Put it on the spit also the QR code doesn't say how or what you need to do its actually:

> Synthetic_even_toed_ungulate_and_neural_terminus_catalyst//DO_NOT_COOK_OR_CONSUME.(c)1958c_S
>   WINOLUXE

Answer (score 0):

There is a spit by where you spawned when you first arrived at the resort.